# Display ArrayList to TextView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do something simple: display my ArrayList to a TextView. I have tried to use methods that would do this without success. Or am I supposed to use a ListView instead of a TextView?

Anyway here is the code. I hope someone can help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button aButton; // Global Scope
    TextView text2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_layout); 

        aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                list.add("Books");
                list.add("Newspapers");
                list.add("Magazines");

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    //System.out.println(list.get(i));

                    Log.i("Results", list.get(i));
                    text2.setText(text2.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing text of TexView:

```
text2.setText(text2.getText());
```

You rather thought about:

```
text2.setText(list.get(i));
```

eventually:

```
text2.setText((text2.getText() != null ? text2.getText() : "") + list.get(i));
```

Comment: Wait, you are telling me that I need to add the "eventually" code underneath my Log.i? Im sorry I just began Java 2 days ago. So I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: just replace text2.setText(text2.getText()); with one of the options and check what happens

Comment: After I run the app I get an Alert from the Emulator saying "Unfortunately AppDemo has Stopped" :/

Comment: Tried to replace with both suggestions

Comment: text2 is null, assign something to it

Comment: Would you be so kind to tell me how to assign something to text2? Thanks multimillion!

Comment: The same way as you did with a button, however I don't know its id.
text2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text2);

Comment: So I could do something like:
text2=textview? or something along those lines?

Comment: use findViewById as you did for button

Comment: You, my friend are a freaking genius!!! It worked!!! Thank you a million! I hope you become rich, powerful and never have to do anything else!!

Comment: Excuse all the excitement :)

Comment: It only shows one of the three items but its a lot already. I need to figure out how to display the other two. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Books");
        list.add("Newspapers");
        list.add("Magazines");
        String listString = "";

        for (String s : list) {
            listString += s + " ";
        }
        text2.setText(listString);
    }
});
```

Comment: I get an Alert from the Emulator saying "Unfortunately AppDemo has Stopped" as well

Comment: This actually helped me get all of my items to be displayed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your prolem is here

**text2.setText(text2.getText())**

The working code will be:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button aButton; // Global Scope
TextView text2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout); 

    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            list.add("Books");
            list.add("Newspapers");
            list.add("Magazines");

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                //System.out.println(list.get(i));

                Log.i("Results", list.get(i));
                text2.setText(list.get(i));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Unfortunately AppDemo has Stopped"